# How to access JSON array with php and concatenate that to html

Tags: php, json

I am using a API to get deals from a shopping website and I get the following JSON response -

```
{
    "update_time": "2020-07-23 22:01:31",
    "offers": [{
        "products": [{
            "title": "Product Name",
            "endDate": "2020-07-24 03:55:01",
            "url": "https://store.com/productid",
            "offerPercent": 87,
            "offerPrice": "12.74",
            "id": "3cbfdc55",
            "normalPrice": "99.99",
            "reviewRating": 4.7428455,
            "imageUrl": "https://store.com/productid/image",
            "totalReviews": "1856"
        }, { //This repeats alot of times
```

I am tried to use PHP to:

1 Retrieve the data into PHP

2 Loop through all of the items, storing all of the parameters, like *url*, *title* etc.

3 Concatenate that with some html (like a div tag) e.g:

```
$html = '';

$html = $html . '<div>Title' . $title .'</div>'; //Repeating this for each item?
```

Is that possible, if so, how? Could you point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**
I used json_decode to convert the json to php (`$someArray json_decode($jsonlink, true);` then I used `foreach` to read the contents

```
foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[1][1];
}
```

And the webpage showed up as blank. *What am I doing wrong.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can convert your json object to php structure by using json_decode in php, this will transform the json to a php array like this.

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
json_decode($json)
```

The output will be like this.

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
["a"] => int(1)
["b"] => int(2)
["c"] => int(3)
["d"] => int(4)
["e"] => int(5)
```

}

After that you have to use a recursive function or a foreach to read the object and then get and print the information that you need.

You can read this info here [PHP json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) [PHP foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Sorry, there was a misunderstanding. I forgot to write that I did use json_decode and for each and it didn't work. I'll edit my post with more info

Comment: Ok, I think the answer below explains better what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

After decoding your JSON using `json_decode` you can loop through the items like this (using provided code as example):

```php
// $raw_json would be the json you received
$data = json_decode($raw_json);

$html = "";
foreach($data->offers as $offer){
    // $offer now has all of the child properties e.g. $offer->products
    foreach($offer->products as $product){
        // $product now has all of the child properties e.g. $product->title
        $html .= "<div>Title: {$product->title}</div>";
    }

}
```

`json_decode` has a second parameter which you can pass `true` to ensure it returns an Associative Array meaning you can access properties like `$variable["propName"]`. This would change the above code to:

```php
// $raw_json would be the json you received
$data = json_decode($raw_json, true);

$html = "";
foreach($data['offers'] as $offer){
    // $offer now has all of the child properties e.g. $offer['products'[
    foreach($offer['products ']as $product){
        // $product now has all of the child properties e.g. $product['title']
        $html .= "<div>Title: {$product['title']}</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. One problem: The element offers has the child element products and in that there is a sub propert(ies) of different items (e.g 1,2) and in those items (e.g item 1) there is description and price etc. How do I access it then?

Comment: @hopefulhacker-ReinstateMonica I've updated the answer - you can use the same approach again inside the `$offers` loop (i.e. create a `$products` loop)

Comment: when I used the following code $jsonlink = file_get_contents('externaljson.txt');
// $raw_json would be the json you received
$data = json_decode($jsonlink, true);

$html = "";
foreach($data['offers'] as $offer){
    // $offer now has all of the child properties e.g. $offer['products'[
    foreach($offer['products ']as $product){
        // $product now has all of the child properties e.g. $product['title']
        $html .= "<div>Title: ". $product["description"] ."</div>";
    }
} the webpage showed  up blank what did I do wrong

Comment: do you want the json?

Comment: @hopefulhacker-ReinstateMonica Did you echo the `$html` variable?

Comment: If you would rather output immediately, you can echo each property: change `$html .= ...` to `echo ...` otherwise, `echo $html;` after the whole loop

Comment: I did echo the $html and it still didn't work. Is something wrong with thejson? would it help to seei it?

Comment: @hopefulhacker-ReinstateMonica I would suggest checking the json and ensuring it has the same structure. You can do a `var_dump($data);` to echo out the result and see if it matches. There could be an issue with the Json, or we're not using the correct structure

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop inside the array that conatains the data you want.

```
$data = json_decode($raw_json);
foreach ($data['offers']['products] as $product) {
    echo $product['title'];
}
```

this is how you display the data on your website.

If you want to display your data with html and css styles:

1. First what i do is copy the html component like a bootstrap card, row, col, etc.
2. then paste it on a variable

```php
$html = '<div>
<h1>here goes my div</h1>
<img src="here/goes/your/url.png" />
<p>Description</p>
</div>';
```

3. Then, replace the dummy data with your own data from the foreach array:

```php
$data = json_decode($raw_json);
 foreach ($data['offers']['products'] as $product) {
  $html = '<div>
  <h1>'.$product['title'].'</h1>
  <img src="'.$product['imageUrl'].'" />
  <p>'.$product['normalPrice'].'</p>
  </div>';
 }
```

4. Finally use echo to render the component

```php
$data = json_decode($raw_json);
 foreach ($data['offers']['products'] as $product) {
  $html = '<div>
  <h1>'.$product['title'].'</h1>
  <img src="'.$product['imageUrl'].'" />
  <p>'.$product['normalPrice'].'</p>
  </div>';
 echo $html;
 }
```

Comment: sure, it may be the data strucuture that doesnt match the foreach loop

Comment: k. the raw json is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/g6Ek2wLD

Comment: it is just a nested foreach what you need, this is an example: [example](https://pastebin.com/p7GQUZXP)